# Can I inject into a hibernate configuration?

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection

I am fairly new to the world of Spring injection and web services. Up to this point, I have developed some simple SOAP and REST services, using a properties file to inject variables that depend on the deployed server (DEV v. QA v. PROD) - things such as usernames and passwords - into beans. Now we are trying to use VisualParadigm tools to automatically generate the database portion of our code. Suddenly I find that the username/password/etc. values for the database are not in an applicationContext.xml file, but instead are located in a project.cfg.xml file located in the src/main/java/ormmapping directory. The contents:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- properties -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer</property>
    <property name="connection.username">{database.username}</property>
    <property name="connection.password">{database.password}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
    <!-- mapping files -->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Where I see the xml element

```
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
```

I tried to replace root with ${database.username}, which refers to a property in my designated .properties file. The result from the logs is that the username is now set to null.

I am using CXF and Maven. I believe it must be finding the properties file; I can see from the STS console that it loads log4j.xml from the same directory, and they are both referenced from web.xml. Is there a way to change the values in project.cfg.xml from hard-coded to injected? [That file is referenced from a .jar file provided by VP, that interfaces the VP-generated code to hibernate code. I hope to not have to modify such a vendor-supplied library.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to import the deployment variables from an external file. I could not get XInclude to work; since the hibernate.cfg.xml file is controlled by a DTD specification, any addition of an `<xi:include>` line generated a 'must match specification' error, and nothing I could figure out allowed me to modify the DTD correctly. However, using an ENTITY replacement worked. To the DOCTYPE declaration, add an ENTITY to specify the external file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"
[ <!ENTITY xinclude SYSTEM "/etc/comporium/com.comporium.customermodel.webservices/hibernate.xml"> ]>
```

and then replace the desired  elements with a single `&xinclude;` -

```
   <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <!-- properties -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        &xinclude;
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
        <!-- mapping files -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The correct deployment file is then placed in the /etc directory. It is not 'well-formed' xml, with no opening elements - it contains only `<property>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to move the hibernate configuration to spring, in there you could use properties as you use for other regular spring bean. The following example was taken from the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup):

```
<beans>

  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
      <list>
        <value>product.hbm.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Francisco! I suspect that I need to do something along those lines. However, I'm not sure how or if to connect those beans into the session-factory that VP generated. There are additional properties defined in the .cfg.xml file that aren't in the beans (do they fit into one of them?). Also, the VP-generated code then calls a wrapper (provided in a .jar) that then calls the hibernate library, and I fear that the wrapper may reference that original .cfg.xml file.